# Getting 100% Accuracy on my DecisionTree Model

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

Here is my code, and it always returns 100% accuracy, regardless of how big the test size is. I used the train_test_split method, so I do not believe there should be any duplicates of data. Could someone inspect my code?

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


data = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')

prices = data['median_house_value']
features = data.drop(['median_house_value', 'ocean_proximity'], axis = 1)

prices.shape
(20640,)

features.shape
(20640, 8)


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, prices, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

X_train = X_train.dropna()
y_train = y_train.dropna()
X_test = X_test.dropna()
y_test = X_test.dropna()

model = DecisionTreeClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

y_train.shape
(16512,)

X_train.shape
(16512, 8)


predictions = model.predict(X_test)
score = model.score(y_test, predictions)
score
```

Comment: What do you mean by "regardless of how big the test size is"? I doubt that if you set test size to be say 90% of the data, the model will still give you 100% accuracy. Moreover, getting 100% accuracy on a simple dataset is not that big of a concern. What does concern me is why you are using `Decision tree classifier` instead of `Decision tree regressor` for house price classification. Maybe that is your answer.

Comment: Why `DecisionTreeClassifier()` ? Is this not a regression problem?

Comment: Please note, this is not overfitting. Overfitting is when your training accuracy is quite high but your validation accuracy is comparatively much lower. This is a sign that your model is fitting very well on your training data but not generalizing on unseen data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT:** I have reworked my answer since I found multiple issues. Please copy-paste the below code to ensure no bugs are left.

Issues -

1. You are using `DecisionTreeClassifier` instead of `DecisionTreeRegressor` for a regression problem.
2. You are removing `nans` after doing the test train split which will mess up the count of samples. Do the `data.dropna()` before the split.
3. You are using the `model.score(X_test, y_test)` incorrectly by passing it `(X_test, predictions)`. Please use `accuracy_score(X_test, predictions)` with those parameters instead, or fix the syntax.

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeRegressor #<---- FIRST ISSUE
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


data = pd.read_csv('housing.csv')

data = data.dropna() #<--- SECOND ISSUE

prices = data['median_house_value']
features = data.drop(['median_house_value', 'ocean_proximity'], axis = 1)

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(features, prices, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)

model = DecisionTreeRegressor()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = model.predict(X_test)
score = accuracy_score(y_test, predictions) #<----- THIRD ISSUE
score
```

Comment: This still returns 100% accuracy

Comment: Could you please change your test data size to 0.9 and tell me what happens?

Comment: It still returns 100% accuracy with 0.9 test data.

Comment: Never mind I found your issue. Please check the model.score statement. you are using it incorrectly. Check my updated comment. Let me know if it fixes it.

Comment: It returns ValueError: y_true and y_pred have different number of output (8!=1)

Comment: Thats because you are dropping `na` after the test train split. Please drop `na` from the dataset before that and then try.

Comment: I have updated my code, please copy-paste it exactly as is and then let me know.

Comment: Fixed it, but very low accuracy for some reason (sorry about all the mistakes I'm very new to using sklearn)

Comment: That's because of the model and hyperparameters. Try using Randomforest regressor and see. Or try better features. Not sure why my answer got a downvote though lol.